# Writing to same topic on kafka

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, confluent-platform

On writing to the same topic on Kafka with the ProduceAsync method on confluent-kafka-dotnet v0.9.5, will it overwrite the data on the default partition and offset (P0, O0) or will it write to the next available offset on the partition?

Answer (score 0):

It will not overwrite. Please refer to the documentation here [Kafka Topics](https://kafka.apache.org/intro#intro_topics)

**Brief explaination**

Kafka works with `pub-sub` mechanism, meaning publishers send data to a topic and there can be multiple of them. The data will be written to current offset and any subscriber who is reading from this topic will be given data as per the consumer offset. The data will be retained to disk in a kafka cluster as per the configuration for desired interval of time or desired size of the file.